# How do I connect to the rails console from googles compute engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed a rails 4.2 app to googles cloud platform using runtime ruby. I have an instance running in googles compute engine that I can SSH onto but I cant locate the apps directory so I can run `rails console` and get the console going.

How can I run the `rials console` on the compute engine instance? As far as I can get is running `sudo su`in the instance and then all directories in there just seem to have dead ends, none lead to the project I deployed.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The instance that you log into will be running your code in a docker container. Try this;

List all the containers that are running:

```
sudo docker ps
```

Find the container that is running your code (look at the command column, it might start with bundle exec etc)

Start a bash shell on the app container

```
container_exec your-app-container-id /bin/bash
```

Once you're in a bash shell of your container, your code will be in /app

```
cd /app
```

If you need to execute a rails console, you'll need to add the right bin folders to your path

```
export PATH=$PATH:/rbenv/versions/2.3.4/bin:/rbenv/bin:/nodejs/bin
cd /app && bundle exec rails c production
```

Comment: How can you also have the same environment variables setup?