# How to access rails console from google app engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

in heroku, i would run `heroku run rails console`

Is there an equivalent command to access my production console for gcloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to access gcloud you need to create an instance in the googles compute engine. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance for more info about that. After that you can access this instance by common SSH tools, then you need to locate where you code actually is on that instance.

You can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44283297/5872935.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing, think this may be the answer. You need to set up a proxy to your local machine, and then run RAILS_ENV=production rails console. Heres the link to the other stackoverflow question

[Rails Migrations on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41450437/rails-migrations-dont-run-on-google-app-engine-deploy)